# Checking form with Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I made a little jQuery Ajax code to check if an email already exists in a DB, i can't have it working right
My Html Code:

```
<form name="emailForm" id="emailForm" method="post" action="signin.php">
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required="required" />
    <input type="submit" value="Get Started Now!" />
</form>
```

The jQuery Code:

```
$(function(){
    $("#emailForm").submit(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type:POST,
            url:"signin.php",
            data: "email="+$("#email").val(),//{email:$("#email").val()},
            success: function(msg){
                if(msg == '1'){
                    alert("Already exists.");
                }else{
                    alert("C'est cool, Hak la suite");
                }
            }

        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

the signin.php code

```
function check_email($email){
    include 'bdd.php';
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email'";
    $resultat = mysqli_query($link,$query);
    $msg = mysqli_num_rows($resultat);
    return $msg;
}
if(isset($_POST['email'])){
    if(check_email($_POST['email']) == 1){
        $msg = "1";
    }else{
        $msg = "0";
    }
}
echo $msg;
```

It goes to signin.php and prints 1 or 0, any ideas how to make the Ajax work?

Comment: Yes it prints 1 or 0, in signin.php page

Comment: It's not the right way to send back data from PHP to jquery?

Comment: POST should be in single or double quotes.

Comment: On a side note, you should consider changing the SQL query as it is wide open for a SQL injection attack in it's current form.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with the following code

```
$(function(){
    $("#emailForm").submit(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type:POST,
            url:"signin.php",
            data: {"email":$("#email").val()},
            success: function(msg){
                if(msg == '1'){
                    alert("Already exists.");
                }else{
                    alert("C'est cool, Hak la suite");
                }
            }

        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Same thing, it echos 0 or 1 in signin.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this one and see if this helps:

```
 $(function () {
  $("#emailForm").submit(function (e) {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST', // in quotes
      url: "signin.php",
      data: {data:$(this).serialize()}, // serialize the form
      success: function (msg) {
        if (msg == '1') {
          alert("Already exists.");
        } else {
          alert("C'est cool, Hak la suite");
        }
      }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```